# preventing unauthorized access to a web application

Tags: php, session, session-variables

i have created two web application for my company and i am checking the user credentials on every page of the application i am validating user using sessions and i am even setting some values into the sessions for the use in entire application but now the problem is when i am using both application on the same machine their sessions are clashing with  each other and the value stored into the sessions also gets overwritten when i login to the another application while the first application is already started
here is my code to check the user in session

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["username"])){
   header("Location: index.php");
}
```

and the value which is set in the session is

```
$_SESSION["zdb"];
```

is there any other way from which i can prevent unauthorized access to my applications??

Comment: Have you ever learned to use punctuation to break text into readable sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could namespace your sessions with a prefix, for example.

Application 1

```
$sess_prefix = 'app1';
if(!isset($_SESSION[$sess_prefix.".username"])){
   header("Location: index.php");
}
```

And application 2

```
$sess_prefix = 'app2';
if(!isset($_SESSION[$sess_prefix.".username"])){
   header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Comment: i tried that too that works fine but my problem is that i am sending some database related information into the sessions for eg. mydatabase <-this is the name of my database which i need in my entire application and it gets overwrite as soon i login into my second application

Comment: That sounds more like a problem of configuration in other places. If your applications use the same table names, you should make sure to use different databases, or prefix the table names as well.

Comment: yup that is the problem i want to use the database name from the sessions inside mysql queries and not even want them to clash with each other

Comment: What's the problem in setting them accordingly? Where do the database names come from?

Comment: well i have a combo box from which user can select the database after login and i store the database name into the session

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [session_set_cookie_params](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php) where you can define parameters (like path and domains which should be diffrent for your applications).

Answer (score 0):

Hello In this manner sure you have to create or destroy session of different name. if you want to use both application same time same browser. Your may also generate id (unique) name session in your application.

Comment: yes but  if i add a prefix to my database inside my session how can i use them in mysql queries?

Comment: You should use different name of database and session attribute. like $_SESSION['appnameUser'] = $userId;

Comment: if you use $_SESSION['appnameUser'] for storing current user id of application. then at starting time when your log it check $_SESSION['appnameUser'] having any id or not then match to your database userId. in another application condition is same but for different session name $_SESSION['secondappUser'] then it should not conflict when using both application in same browser.
thanks